# Seconds to ticks conversion

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building a fnaf map for me and my friends to play, and need to convert seconds to ticks.

I read on the wiki that a night is 8m 36s, which is 516s altogether. I want to convert 516s to game ticks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Minecraft [game tick](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tick) is 1/20s:

> Minecraft's game loop normally runs at a fixed rate of 20 ticks per second, so one tick happens every 0.05 seconds. An in-game day lasts exactly 24000 ticks, or 20 minutes.

Your 516s translate to 516s * 20 ticks/s = 10320 ticks.

Comment: well you were 30secs faster :D

Comment: @Nitro.de or 600 ticks

Answer (score 7):

> Minecraft's game loop normally runs at a fixed rate of 20 ticks per
> second, so one tick happens every 0.05 seconds. An in-game day lasts
> exactly 24000 ticks, or 20 minutes

So your question is
516s * 20 ticks/s = 10320 ticks.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tick)

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft game ticks are 20 ticks to 1 second, that means you can simply multiply 20 to 516, and the answer is 10320 ticks.
But if your computer is slow, it may lose some ticks and the time will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If fast nights power up is on it should be about 39 repeaters set to 4ticks- the max, optionally followed by a command block.
CB Details:

- Hover note: Time:
- Block Type: Impulse
- Condition: Unconditional
- Redstone: Needs Redstone
- Execute on first tick: Off
- Delay in ticks: 0 (or you can get rid of all but one repeater and type 516 here, that would give you regular nights though.)
- Command input: `/say [time]:00 AM`
- Previous output: On